# angular shows error : webpack CLI failed to load

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am trying to create my react application from scratch but my webpack.config.js is giving me errors saying [webpack CLI ] failed to load

Below is the webpack.config.js code

```js
    const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require(“html-webpack-plugin”);
    const htmlPlugin = new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
     template: “./src/index.html”,
     filename: “./index.html”
    });
    module.exports = {
    mode: ‘development’,
      module: {
        rules: [{
       test: /\.js$/,
       exclude: /node_modules/,
       use: {
         loader: “babel-loader”
       }
     },
      {
       test: /\.css$/,
       use: [“style-loader”, “css-loader”]
      }
    ]},
     plugins: [htmlPlugin]
    };
```

Above is the code giving me errors in the webpack.config.js

Comment: Is webpack-cli installed?

Comment: yes i have installed it

Comment: "webpack": "^5.52.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.8.0",
    "